# How to implement Grid header which support scrolling in proper way?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid, grid

Is there any way to implement Grid header(on any way, can be separated Grid or whatever) that act like DataGrid header?

All that I need is that header allow me to use horizontal and vertical scrollbar in proper way(header is always visible when I use vertical scrollbar, and header is moving if I use horizontal scrollbar).

I don't need sorting or reordering columns etc.(possible with DataGrid header)

Comment: have you already tried ListView / GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need some special functionality: you could try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614041/GridView-with-Fixed-Header-and-Scroll-Bar.